# how can a visitor share a picture on instagram from my php website through android and iphone? Is it possible in php?

Tags: php, android, iphone, instagram, sharing

I am looking for the code through which any visitor can share links and images from my website using 'inst-a-gram' sharing button on his/her 'android and i-phone mobile'. Can anyone explain with an example please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Instagram API does not allow you to post pictures.
You are still required to post images by using the Instagram application.

Please check the Instagram API documentation. There is no endpoint for creating media. [API instagram docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Comment: Thanks for your response Satish. can I share text or a link using inst-a-gram sharing button on my website?

Comment: you cannot share using ur website.